# Issue In calling web api. Always returns 500 server error

Tags: c#, api, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am making an HttpWeb request , "POST" to call url/api with basic authentication of username and password.It gives response when I use POSTMAN tool.But not sure why the .net code is giving me Internal server error.Below is what I am trying:

Note : The interchange data must be XML format.Hence I have provided text/xml

```
var requestXml = new XElement("transaction", new XElement("transactionId", "Dummy"));
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                byte[] bytes;
                bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XMLSerializer(requestXml));
                request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                request.Method = "POST";               
                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));              
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                HttpWebResponse response;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                    return responseStr;
                }
```

Comment: try adding a space after "Basic" i.e. "Basic "

Comment: checkout the error on server side. And compare your raw .net request with your postman request using something like fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization header should be set to:

```
"Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));
```

rather than

```
"Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));
```

notice the extra space character after Basic.